# Difference between --db-security-groups and --vpc-security-group-ids in RDS set up using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to create an AWS RDS using CLI, usually I create it using AWS Console. When I try to create an RDS instance, I saw these 2 parameters:

1. --db-security-groups
2. --vpc-security-group-ids

What is the difference between these 2 values? I couldn't find a value related to --db-security-groups via the console. These are the definitions that AWS provides in the documentation:

> **--db-security-groups (list)**
>
> A list of DB security groups to associate with this DB instance.
>
> Default: The default DB security group for the database engine.
>
> **--vpc-security-group-ids (list)**
>
> A list of Amazon EC2 VPC security groups to associate with this DB
> instance.
>
> Amazon Aurora Not applicable. The associated list of EC2 VPC security
> groups is managed by the DB cluster.
>
> Default: The default EC2 VPC security group for the DB subnet group's
> VPC.

I still couldn't understand, what is the difference. Or is there any security group specific to DB only?

Comment: It's legacy stuff. If in doubt, always use the option that mentions **VPC**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html):

> DB security groups are used with DB instances that are not in a VPC and on the EC2-Classic platform.

These days you would use only `vpc-security-group-ids`, unless you have old aws account.

The detailed comparison is also in [the docs](DB security groups vs. VPC security groups):

- [DB security groups vs. VPC security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.Compare)